# import and render md file in react-native

Tags: markdown, react-native

I have a few `md` files that I want to render in a react-native app.
The problem is that when I try to import them (using `import` or `require`), I always get this error:

`error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module`

so I don't see how I can import an md file in order to render it (using probably a library like [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) or [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown).

Comment: Are you using expo or vanilla react native?

Comment: Did you tried this ? https://github.com/tradle/rn-markdown

Comment: @Filipe I am using vanilla react native.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have many files, the best option is to convert them to template literals, and to .js files, something like so:

Initial:
example.md

```
# markdown
something else
```

Final:
example.js

```
const example = `# markdown
something else
`;
export default example;
```

and then, you would be able to use, for example, `react-native-simple-markdown` to render it like so:

```
<SimpleMarkdown>
    {example}
</SimpleMarkdown>
```

Even if there are many files, if they will already be bundled with the app, you can set up a script, or maybe a gulp task, to convert them before building the app.

However, if the user will be uploading these files, or you don't like this solution, there might be another way, either accessing the file system or using a local website inside the app.

Comment: Using template literals will convert every line break, including the first one after ` in your example, as well as convert the tab/spaces indents into spaces.

Comment: I'd guess then using \n and \t should solve this problem